# How do I update a value within an array in Ravendb? I need to use Query

Tags: ravendb, raven, ravendb-studio, ravendb4

I have several documents. Below I will list just two.
How do I update the value of the "Value field" that is below the "Name field: StartDate" in all documents?

Example:
10/10/2019 to 09/09/2019
01/01/2019 to 09/09/2019

Document 1:

```
{
    "IdLoginTwm": 4330,
    "Parametros": [
        {
            "Name": "UserName",
            "Value": "diego.guiando@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "Name ": "StartDate",
            "Value ": "10/10/2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
    "IdLoginTwm": 4330,
    "Parametros": [
        {
            "Name": "UserName",
            "Value": "diego.guiando@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "Name ": "FirstName",
            "Value ": "diego"
        },  
        {
            "Name ": "StartDate",
            "Value ": "01/01/2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PatchByQueryOperation() for this.

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/operations/patching/set-based#patching-how-to-perform-set-based-operations-on-documents

The patch script should be similar to below

```
from Logins
update {
    var res = this.Parametros.filter(x => x.Name == "StartDate")
    if (res.length > 0)
    {
        res.forEach(x => x.Value = 'NULL')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I try this but not work.


from Logins as l where l.Parametros.Nome = 'StartDate'
update  
{
  for(var i = 0; i < this.Parametros.length; i++ ){
     if( this.Parametros[i].Name == 'StartDate') 
         this.Parametros[i].Value = 'NULL';
  }
}